# Dynamic memory allocation with array and pointers fail to print

Tags: c++

I tried to print a array of characters using dynamic memory allocation with pointer. If i comment one pf the variables work, but when i tried to print both the program stop.

This is Main CPP.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ContactInfo.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
int n = 0;
char *ph, *nm;
ContactInfo *allcontacts;

cout << "How many people you want to add to phone book? ";
cin >> n;
allcontacts = new ContactInfo[n];

for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << i + 1 << ") Name: ";
    cin >> nm;
    allcontacts[i].setName(nm);
    cout << i + 1 << ") Phone: ";
    cin >> ph;
    allcontacts[i].setPhone(ph);
}

cout << setw(8) <<"Name" << setw(8) << "Phone\n";
cout << "------------------------------------------------------\n";

for (int i=0; i < n; i++){
   allcontacts[i].display();
}
return 0;
}
```

CPP

```
#include "ContactInfo.h"

void ContactInfo::setName(char *n) {
name = new char[strlen(n) + 1];
strcpy(name, n);
}

void ContactInfo::setPhone(char *p) {
phone = new char[strlen(p) + 1];
strcpy(phone, p);
}

ContactInfo::ContactInfo() {
// setName("");
// setPhone("");
}

ContactInfo::ContactInfo(char *n, char *p) {
setName(n);
setPhone(p);
}

ContactInfo::~ContactInfo() {
delete [] name;
delete [] phone;
name = nullptr;
phone = nullptr;
}

const char *ContactInfo::getName() const {
return name;
}

void ContactInfo::display() const {
cout << getName();
cout << getPhoneNumber();
cout << endl;
}

const char *ContactInfo::getPhoneNumber() const {
return phone;
}
```

HEADER

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cstring> // Needed for strlen and strcpy
 using namespace std;

// ContactInfo class declaration.
class ContactInfo
{

private:
char *name; // The contact's name
char *phone; // The contact's phone number

public:
    ContactInfo(char *, char *);
    ContactInfo();
    void setName(char *);
    void setPhone(char *);
    ~ContactInfo();
    const char *getName() const;
    const char *getPhoneNumber() const;
    void display() const;
   };
```

Ouput

How many people you want to add to phonebook? 2

1) Name: www

1) Phone: 22

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Your rubber duck wants to know what `nm` in `main` points to.

Comment: @user4581301 It is well defined: `char *ph, *nm;`.

Comment: @idmean those are definitions. They define pointer variables, but do not point them anywhere. Using an uninitialized pointer leads to all manner of bad.

Comment: nm = name and ph = phone. @idmean thanks. I will initialized.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing C and C++ code together. You have to use `std::string` for your input instead of `char*`. Try following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

class ContactInfo {
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string phone;

public:
    ContactInfo() {
    }

    ContactInfo(const std::string &Name, const std::string &Phone) {
        name = Name;
        phone = Phone;
    }

    void display() const {
        std::cout << name << " " << phone << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    int n = 0;
    std::cout << "How many people you want to add to phone book? ";
    std::cin >> n; std::cin.get();

    std::vector<ContactInfo> all_contacts;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::string name, phone;
        std::cout << i + 1 << ") Name: ";
        std::cin >> name;
        std::cout << i + 1 << ") Phone: ";
        std::cin >> phone;

        all_contacts.push_back(ContactInfo(name, phone));
    }

    std::cout << std::setw(8) << "Name" << std::setw(8) << "Phone" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;

    for (auto i : all_contacts) {
        i.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```